# styling image_tag and slick carousel?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a full-screen carousel, but all of my pictures display in the top left corner of the screen even if I put "align: center"

here is my html...

```js
<div class="scroller">
  <div> <%= image_tag("tokyo.jpg", options = {align: "center", height: "500px"}) %> </div>
  <div><%= image_tag("dolphin.jpg", :style => "align: center;")  %></div>
  <div><%= image_tag("heart.jpg", :style => "height: 635px;")  %></div>
</div>
```

I have tried styling it from a stylesheet as well, i'm not sure why it isn't working... this is what it looks like. Also for some reason, the left arrow doenst appear on any of the pictures, while the one on the right appears on all of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
<div class="scroller">
  <div> <%= image_tag("tokyo.jpg", options = {align: "center", height: "100%"}) %> </div>
  <div><%= image_tag("dolphin.jpg", :style => "align: center;")  %></div>
  <div><%= image_tag("heart.jpg", :style => "height: 635px;")  %></div>
</div>
```